# Search Operation in table view javafx

Tags: javafx

In my application i added all data into table view. Then I need entire row by using search operation.

Searching is based upon any data like search by `RegisterNo` or search by `Name`. By entering `RegisterNo` it Should display entire row related to `RegisterNo`.

Answer (score 0):

To do search operation in a TableView, what I've done is to add a notion of filters.

For example if you want to filter by name, each time your name query change, you filter all your data and let on the table only those who match your query.

You always keep the full data to execute your query on it, but to display it use an other list.

with that I'm able to have lot of filters at the same moment and my view refresh in real time